# NanoStringDiff Counts are not recognized as numeric

Tags: r, bioconductor, transcription

I'm trying to use the `NanoStringDiff` package to perform a differential gene expression analysis

However, when I try to construct the data set with the function `NanoStringData = createNanoStringSetFromCsv(path, header = TRUE, designs)`, I keep receiving the error message:

> Error in rowSums(counts) : 'x' must be numeric"

Here it follows a section from my datasheet:

```
 Code.Class                      Name         Accession  Neg1  Neg2  Neg3  Neg4  Neg5  Neg6  Neg7  Neg8  Neg9 Neg10
1       Positive                POS_A(128)      ERCC_00117.1 45453 40894 34717 41316 70468 55628 59547 62007 46769 53269
2       Positive                 POS_B(32)      ERCC_00112.1 14424 12902 11005 13898 22849 18664 20197 20309 15565 17069
3       Positive                  POS_C(8)      ERCC_00002.1  3967  3666  3156  3887  6246  4990  5305  5460  4207  4723
4       Positive                  POS_D(2)      ERCC_00092.1   935   880   714   866  1501  1212  1222  1269   970  1140
5       Positive                POS_E(0.5)      ERCC_00035.1   157   120   141   150   246   193   193   185   135   178
6       Positive              POS_F(0.125)      ERCC_00034.1    67    59    43    53   117    86    95    84    78    83
```

Now, an example of my code and the error message:

```
directory <- "C:/Users/san_c/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/Nanostring/Analise1_GCBHIV_GCBNEG"
path <- paste(directory, "datasetGCB.csv",sep="/")

NanoStringData = createNanoStringSetFromCsv(path, header = TRUE, designs)
Error in rowSums(counts) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Has anyone else been receiving this message?

Comment: There is some issue with your csv file. Because if i use the example you provided, everything is ok. Most likely you need to check the csv file first by reading it using read.csv

Comment: If you share the file somehow, I might be able to check it for you

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is that your first three column headers will be `'Code.Class'`, `'Name'`, and `'Accession'`. Make sure your data are saved as `.csv`